# How to change the specific cell image respect to indexpath in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uitableview

I am working with the tableview and Sqlite when i update my Table based on the values i need to change the image which is in tableview cell it is also working fine but when i scroll then my images are changing below is my code

Sqlite Table Update

```
[DBObject upDateTable:@"Green" :messageID];
```

How i am fetching values from my array

```
  NSString *messageStatus = [[messageArray1 objectAtIndex:index] ColorStatus];
```

now I am checking colorStatus like below in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {

           cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-Green.png"];

        [[ASNGlobalClass shareManager] setIsDelivered:YES];
    }else if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
        cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-Red.png"];
    }else if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {
        cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-yellow.png"];
    }
```

my images are assigning perfectly but when i scroll then it is changing i don't know where i am missing please help me out

Comment: put else condition at the end with set image to nil

Comment: where you put  `NSString *messageStatus = [[messageArray1 objectAtIndex:index] ColorStatus];` ?

Comment: for checking purpose i am using above line like if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {

Comment: can you please add code for cell in cellForRowAtindexPath?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Sorry I am not getting you?

Comment: Means you are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Comment: when you update the color for cell image?

Comment: when i got message from server then i am updating table and reflect to tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
     cell.playButtonImageView.image=nil;  // write this line before set image
     if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {

           cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-Green.png"];

        [[ASNGlobalClass shareManager] setIsDelivered:YES];
    }else if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
        cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-Red.png"];
    }else if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {
        cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-yellow.png"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {
    cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-Green.png"];
    [[ASNGlobalClass shareManager] setIsDelivered:YES];
}else if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
    cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-Red.png"];
}else if ([messageStatus isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {
    cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-yellow.png"];
}
else
    cell.playButtonImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"some-default-image-placeholder.png"];  // some-default-image-placeholder.png is an placeholder image name
```

Comment: no i need to work with three images must. I tried with nil also in else

Comment: You need to debug for messageStatus value and make sure it has atleast one value from Green,Red, Yellow than it will never execute else loop.

Comment: Thanksfor the replay. yes you right but  every time it will be green if i change  some thing than i will change image respect to index path

Comment: If on scroll your cell image changes than for sure it fails to get into any if or else if block so it's displaying old cell image(i.e. before reuse). so try to log  messageStatus value for each cell and make sure  it has atleast one value from Green,Red,Yellow.

Comment: Thanks for the replay i will try

Comment: and one more thing my images are changing like when i scroll suppose top image is red then last image also changed to red like that any way i will try thanks

Comment: Yes, When you scroll thn top cell go under reuse process and that comes as a last cell & if it contains red image than defiantly if it reused for last cell than it will contain red image.